# How to make two processes run alternately to avoid conflicts?

Tags: multiprocessing, synchronization

There are two processes that conflict with each other and I want them to run alternately without conflict. And both need to be called up during each one-minute period. Process A will run for about 30 seconds once it is called up, and process B will run for about 10 seconds once it is called up.

I can think of two approaches, but both have flaws.

- Method one is to use file locks for synchronization. Conflicts caused
  by simultaneous running can be avoided, but once one of the processes
  runs longer than expected, the other process will not be started
  within the corresponding one-minute period.
- The second method is to specify the running time of each process. For
  example, process A can only run for the first 40 seconds of a minute,
  and process B can only run for the left 20 seconds. Each process will
  actively exit if it finds that it has timed out during the running
  process. This requires adding time judgment logic to the process,
  which brings additional overhead.

**Is there a more efficient and elegant way to achieve this functionality?**

Comment: Run each from a parent process which waits for completion of the subprocess before going on to the next: ([using python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run): `from subprocess import run; run("taska"); run("taskb")`)